# Logging query response time at load-balancer

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, haproxy

I have three MySQL database servers setup with master-master circular replication. The replication is working, so that is good.
I am using [HAProxy for loadbalancing](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-to-set-up-mysql-load-balancing--3) with rsyslog,
here is my haproxy.cfg:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log global
    retries 2
    timeout connect 3000
    timeout server 5000
    timeout client 5000

listen mysql-cluster
    bind 0.0.0.0:3306
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    log global
    option mysql-check user haproxy_check
    balance roundrobin
    server database1 10.2.10.102:3306 check
    server database2 10.2.10.103:3306 check
    server database3 10.2.10.104:3306 check
```

I have uncommented the following lines from /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
# provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
$UDPServerRun 514

# provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
```

and this in /etc/rsyslog.d/haproxy.conf:

```
if ($programname == 'haproxy') then -/var/log/haproxy.log
```

The log is working in a way:

```
May 27 18:44:38 localhost haproxy[26517]: Proxy mysql-cluster started.
May 27 18:44:38 localhost haproxy[26517]: Proxy mysql-cluster started.
May 27 18:45:02 localhost haproxy[26535]: Proxy mysql-cluster started.
```

But it does not show any entries for requests to MySQL such as when I run this command on the HAproxy VM:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u haproxy_root -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -e "show tables in mydatabase"
```

My HAproxy version is 1.5
I want to know if I can log response times for MySQL queries in HAproxy, and how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
```

Remove the word `notice` and restart HAProxy.  Using `notice` has reduced the amount of logging the proxy generates.

Not, however, that this change will only result in logging connections, which will be logged along with their timers when the connection disconnects.

HAProxy cannot log query response times, because HAProxy with `mode tcp` is not operating as something that could be properly described as a "MySQL proxy."  HAProxy is a tcp connection proxy.  Its job is to identify a server to use for each incoming connection (not each query), establish the connection, and hold it open for the client and server to exchange data.  HAProxy does not attempt to "understand" the data being exchanged, so it is unaware of any meaning of the data being exchanged.

MySQL connections, unlike HTTP connections, are stateful. Creating a temporary table, starting a transaction, setting a user defined variable (e.g. `SET @foo = 'bar';`), and many other actions leave your current MySQL connection in a certain specific  "state" that makes it not interchangeable with any other current MySQL connection, so there is little reason for HAProxy to be aware of the higher layers, and there are good reasons for it not to be, such as the ability to use the [splice(2)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splice_(system_call)) system call for highly efficient proxying of TCP payloads... which can only be used when the payload is locally "uninteresting."

---

By contrast, [MariaDB Maxscale](https://mariadb.com/products/mariadb-maxscale) is a payload aware Layer 7 proxy for MySQL.  It can do a number of interesting things like transparent read/write splitting and logging of all the queries executed on each connection into a file.

(It's hard to tell from the web site that it is available for free download, but it is.  I am not affiliated with MariaDB.)

This is not to say that Maxscale is "better than" HAProxy, which is an established product with a good history of reliability and security... only that its purpose and capabilities are different.

Comment: So is there another way to log query response times in MySQL? Just need end-to-end response time for a single select query.

Comment: You should be able to do that with MaxScale.  See https://mariadb.com/blog/which-sql-queries-take-all-time-using-maxscale-answer-age-old-question

Comment: And will it work with MySQL or will I have to switch to MariaDB?